# DcouSign inbox is empty

Tags: docusignapi, powerform

I am using DocuSign power form. I used to get emails in the inbox of the manage section. But now it is only available in the 'sent' items. Are there any settings required to change to get the emails in the inbox and the person who signed the document also required to receive the email?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Inbox" in DocuSign refers to things you need to sign. It's not about emails/messages from DocuSign sent to you.
If you want you can create another folder and save copies of the envelopes (or move them) in that folder. You can do that programmatically via an integration or manually via the UI.
You can also add a CC to the envelope to send a copy to a specific user if you want. The PowerForm is based on a template, so you change the template that is linked to it to achive this.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Let me check to add CC to a specific user.